# Retrieve data from database in asp.net using vb

Tags: vb.net

Below is the code for fetching the data into textbox but its not working it shows **error no data exits row/column** whereas data and datafield are perfectly alright.
Please help.

```
    Dim Connection As OleDbConnection
    Connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("/db/QardanHasana.mdb"))
    Connection.Open()

    Dim ejamaatregcmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim ejamaatregdtrdr As OleDbDataReader
    ejamaatregcmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT ITSData.[EJamaatID], ITSData.[ITSFirstName] FROM ITSData WHERE  EjamaatID= @EjamaatID", Connection)
    ejamaatregcmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@EjamaatID", txtEjamaatID.Text))
    ejamaatregdtrdr = ejamaatregcmd.ExecuteReader()


    If ejamaatregdtrdr.HasRows Then
        txtFirstName.Text = ejamaatregdtrdr.item("ITSFirstName").ToString()
    end if
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error you get?

Answer (score 1):

A DataReader needs a call to [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to position itself on the first record retrieved

```
ejamaatregdtrdr = ejamaatregcmd.ExecuteReader()
If ejamaatregdtrdr.HasRows Then
     ejamaatregdtrdr.Read()
     txtFirstName.Text = ejamaatregdtrdr.item("ITSFirstName").ToString()
End if
```

By the way, Read returns false if there are no rows to read, so you could remove the test for HasRows and write simply

```
ejamaatregdtrdr = ejamaatregcmd.ExecuteReader()
If ejamaatregdtrdr.Read() Then
     txtFirstName.Text = ejamaatregdtrdr.item("ITSFirstName").ToString()
End if
```

Another suggestion to improve your code is to start using the [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

```
Using Connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;....")
Using ejamaatregcmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ITSData.[EJamaatID], ITSData.[ITSFirstName] FROM ITSData WHERE  EjamaatID= @EjamaatID", Connection)
    Connection.Open()
    ejamaatregcmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@EjamaatID", txtEjamaatID.Text))
    Using ejamaatregdtrdr = ejamaatregcmd.ExecuteReader()
        If ejamaatregdtrdr.Read() Then
           txtFirstName.Text = ejamaatregdtrdr.item("ITSFirstName").ToString()
       End if
    End Using
End Using
End Using
```

The using statement is invaluable to help you to close and dispose the disposable objects like the connection, the command and the reader. Lacking a proper dispose your code uses more memory and locks resources resulting in a more unstable application.

Answer (score 0):

Before reading data from a DataReader, you need to move the row to the first row by calling the [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. It returns true if data exist, so you don't need to check the `HasRows` property:

```
ejamaatregdtrdr = ejamaatregcmd.ExecuteReader()
If ejamaatregdtrdr.Read() Then
    txtFirstName.Text = ejamaatregdtrdr.Item("ITSFirstName").ToString()
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

*I'll generally do something like the following*

```
Function GetResult(ID As string) As String
    GetResult = "No Data" 'Default Result
Dim conn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = *NewConnectionObject*
Dim comm As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand = *NewCommmandObject*
comm.Parameter.AddWithValue("@Parametername",ID)

    Using reader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            'Reader has data, so iterate through it
            GetResult = ""
            while reader.read
               GetResult += reader("FirstName")
            End While
        Else
            'Either Do Nothing - Default Result will show
            'Throw New System.Exception("Empty Data") 'Try Catch Statement have overhead.. so it's not a popular methodology
            'Or Log Something.. 
        End If
    End Using
    If conn.state = connection.open Then
        conn.close
    End
End Function
```